# How to compute very large numbers without a list

Tags: python

I am trying to complete a coding challenge which requires me to count all of the digits between 1 and X, where can reach up to 400,000,000,000,000,000

My approach was to iterate over a list and add the amount of digits to my result in the end, like so:

```
def page_digits(pages):
    list_of_pages = list(range(1, pages + 1))
    res = 0
    for num in list_of_pages:
        res += len((str(num)))
    return res
```

but obviously creating a list of every digit between 1 and that big number requires a lot of storage and running this returns 'MemoryError Line 2'

How else could I go about this? or Avoid the problem

Comment: Could you give a sample input and output?

Comment: how many numbers between 0-9, all of these have 1 digit, how many digits between 10-99, these all have 2 digits, how many between 100-999  these all have 3 digits .... find the pattern solve the puzzle

Comment: A sample input would be 100, output would be 192 in this case, ah I see, so my solution was fundamentally wrong, thank you (i don’t know how to @ someone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def page_digits(pages):
    n = len(str(pages))
    return (sum(int(i * 9 * 10**(i - 1)) for i in range(n))
            + (pages - 10**(n - 1) + 1) * n)
```

This has a much lower complexity (it's basically constant, as your `pages` number will not have more than 20 digits).

A few examples:

```
>>> page_digits(20)
31
>>> page_digits(2)
2
>>> page_digits(100000)
488895
>>> page_digits(100)
192
```

The solution relies on the fact that there are `n * 9 * 10**(n - 1)` digits in numbers that have a total of n digits.

Comment: yup it worked, although I can't say I fully understand the maths behind it. Thank you very much internet stranger

Answer (score 6):

There's no reason you need to turn the range into a list.

```
>>> def page_digits(pages):
...     res = 0
...     for num in range(1, pages + 1):
...         res += len(str(num))
...     return res
...
>>> page_digits(100000)
488895
```

Calling the `list` constructor forces each element from the range to be stored in memory individually, but a regular `range` object is very memory-efficient (it just contains the args you passed it on construction) while still being iterable.

The only reason you might ever need to convert a range into a list would be to mutate individual elements of it (which you can't do with a range).

Comment: Just a heads-up that this is a challenge from [well-known coding challenge site] and cannot be solved by brute force. The range is too large for the time allowed.

Comment: I suspected as much, but understanding the efficiency difference between a `range` and `list` is important in its own right even if the ultimate solution involves using a more complex mathematical formula (and OP's immediate question was about reducing memory usage).

Comment: Yeah sadly the range is as sj said and wayyy to big for my approach to work, thank you very much for the answer and explanation on memory efficiency regarding ranges and lists regardless